# Encoding error when adding SSH key to Heroku

Tags: heroku, ssh-keys

I tried adding SSH key to Heroku, but I got this error

```
Uploading SSH public key C:/Users/xxxx/.ssh/id_rsa.pub... failed
  !     Encoding error. Please ensure that all data in the request can be interpreted as UTF-8.
```

The only thing that comes to mind is checking if the file containing the key is saved with UTF-8 encoding, which it is.

Answer (score 0):

your username is probably non-English character   this is the reason
change your user name to English and restart your computer couple of time (the new user name will appear on `Git Bash` )  and then try (on `Git bash`) :-
1- generate new keys
 `$ ssh-keygen -t rsa`
2-upload the new keys
 `$ heroku keys:add`